# Rails 5: How do I point fixtures to other fixtures?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I three models `Comment`, `User` and `Project`. `Project` and `Comment` need to point to other objects in order to be valid. For example, a comment needs to point to an author (user) and a project.

The associated fixture files look like this:

```
# comments.yml
test_comment:
  author: users(:test_user)
  project: projects(:test_project)

# users.yml
test_user:
  name: 'test user'

# projects.yml
test_project:
  name: 'Test'
  description: 'This is a test'
  owner: users(:test_user)
```

However, I've found that my fixtures are probably set up incorrectly. Rails returns `false` if I try to save the comment:

```
assert_equal true, comments(:test_comment)
#=> false
```

I can see that there are foreign keys for a project and author:

```
=> #<Comment:0x00007f9b1661f3d8
 id: 137725605,
 body: "",
 project_id: 745075726,
 author_id: "31ceee04-5307-5059-91db-0dc2068a780c",
 created_at: Fri, 22 Feb 2019 13:17:58 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Fri, 22 Feb 2019 13:17:58 UTC +00:00>
```

But when I interrogate them, Rails returns `nil`.

```
> comments(:test_comment).author
=> nil

> comments(:test_comment).project
=> nil
```

I expected that one would return `users(:test_user)` and the other would return `projects(:test_project)`. I thought perhaps I needed to use ERB in my yaml:

```
test_comment:
  author: <%= users(:test_user) %>
  project: <%= projects(:test_project) %>
```

But that results is a stream of errors when I run my tests:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `users' for #<#<Class:0x00007f9b17692ff8>:0x00007f9b17692dc8>
```

What do I need to do to point fixtures to other fixtures? Can it be done? What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Rails guide on Testing with YAML fixtures](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#yaml), you can see that you don't need `users(:test_user)` to refer to some other object. Instead, you can simply write `test_user`:

```
# comments.yml
test_comment:
  author: test_user
  project: test_project

# users.yml
test_user:
  name: 'test user'

# projects.yml
test_project:
  name: 'Test'
  description: 'This is a test'
  owner: test_user
```

Hope this helps!